# How to allow cors on nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, rest, fetch, backend

I have a super simple backend with node.js, and I have CORS enabled. However, I still can't get to allow sending any kind of data cross-origin.

This is my backend running on port 3000:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//app.use(cors()); ALSO TRIED THIS

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});


app.get('/number', (req, res) => {
    res.json({number: 1});
});
```

And this is how I fetch from frontend, running on port 3001:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/number')
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

But this is the response I'm getting:

```
Response {
    body: ReadableStream
    bodyUsed: false
    headers: Headers {}
    ok: true
    redirected: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    type: "cors"
    url: "http://localhost:3000/number"
}
```

But I was expecting:

```
Response {
    number:1
}
```

I think this is mainly a CORS issue, because everything works just fine when using postman.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Are you receiving a CORS error in your browser's dev console? If not, then it's not a CORS error. If you are, we need to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the cors issue, simply change your `fetch` like a blow to get the expected result.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/number')
    .then(res => res.json()).then(data=>console.log(data));
```

this will give you `{number: 1}` as a result.